# Burn the [vanilla.js] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I've created the tag not knowing that vanilla was a joke.  I was told that it was, it is no longer on any questions.  Please burn [vanilla.js](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vanilla.js),  it should smell good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this tag is not currently used in any question, it will eventually wither away into nothingness (provided that it isn't used again until then).